# Using JavaScript and PHP to create a chatbot

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest, chat

I have a chat server. I would like to know if I can use JavaScript for the XHR polling, and then pass the data to a PHP script for processing, then back to JavaScript so that it can send the message to the chat server and thus displayed to all users connected. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using web sockets.

A quick google search yields a php library called [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

Web sockets essentially create a tunnel between the server and the client so that the server can push/broadcast to all clients.

For example when a user types a message and sends it to the server, the server could then broadcast it to all of the clients. This was you don't have to have javascript constantly polling for updated messages.

I don't have experience with Ratchet but I do have experience with web sockets. I would combine it with some sort of front end javascript framework such as [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/)

Comment: To be more descriptive. This "bot" will act as a user in the chatroom. It will recieve commands from users and then perform tasks based on what they wanted. Finally sending a message notifying them that the task is complete.